# Email failed to send: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Tags: php, mysql, gmail, phpmailer, html-email

I was trying to configure PHP to use Gmail and he had the following problem

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);                           
    try { 
        $mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";                    
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 1;                       
        $mail->isSMTP();                              
        $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
        $mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false;
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                    
        $mail->Username = 'xxxx';             
        $mail->Password = 'xxxx';         
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                            
        $mail->Port = 465;  

        $mail->setFrom('xxxx@gmail.com', 'Mailer');  //addresser
        $mail->addAddress($email, $username);  // recipients

        $mail->addReplyTo('xxxx@gmail.com', 'info'); 

        $mail->isHTML(true);                        
        $mail->Subject = 'Here's the subject of the email' . time();
        $mail->Body = '<h1>Here's the message</h1>' . date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $mail->AltBody = 'Displays this content if the mail client does not support HTML';

        $mail->send();
        echo 'send an e-mail success';
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'e-mail sending failed: ', $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
```

> SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Comment: So what happened when you followed the link to the troubleshooting guide and did what it said?

Comment: ssl encryption on port 587 won't work.

Comment: I can see `$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;` so you possibly didn't even follow the tips.

Comment: did you enable [less secure apps](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en) in your google account?

Comment: I have tried various methods, but he still reported this error. Is there a problem with my smtp configuration?

Comment: The following is the latest errorSMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Comment: Both authentication application passwords are set